# Is the Jacobian different for different ${\cal L}^p$ norms?

Tags: coordinate-systems, integration, mathematics

(I posted this to the math stackexchange, but I've yet to receive an answer so I figured I should post here too, as this forum seems faster to respond and is full of knowledgable people.)

Because the Jacobian is related to the measure of an integral, and the measure is related to the norm/metric of the space, does the Jacobian behave differently for ${\cal L}^p$ spaces where $p$ isn't $2$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is the same. The measure in the integral itself has little to do with the weighting of the integrand in the $L^p$ norm.

Indeed when we use differential forms to define  integrals on manifolds, the measure in the sense of a measure-theory notion of an "element of volume" on  is not involved at all. Each  differential form comes equiped with its own  notion of measure, and the Jacobian describes how the forms change when we change the co-ordinate system.